# Some questions about "NSStringCompareOptions" struct document in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I just stuck in swift's document that explain how "NSStringCompareOptions" works. Just some newb questions.

```
struct NSStringCompareOptions : OptionSetType {
init(rawValue rawValue: UInt)
static var CaseInsensitiveSearch: NSStringCompareOptions { get }
static var LiteralSearch: NSStringCompareOptions { get }
static var BackwardsSearch: NSStringCompareOptions { get }
static var AnchoredSearch: NSStringCompareOptions { get }
static var NumericSearch: NSStringCompareOptions { get }
static var DiacriticInsensitiveSearch: NSStringCompareOptions { get }
static var WidthInsensitiveSearch: NSStringCompareOptions { get }
static var ForcedOrderingSearch: NSStringCompareOptions { get }
static var RegularExpressionSearch: NSStringCompareOptions { get }
}
```

and this struct contains "init" in it, when I call NSStringCompareOptions()
Why it allows the init method "rawValue" to be omitted?

and another question is that I know

```
NSStringCompareOptions()
```

is the new version as

```
NSStringCompareOptions.allZero
```

and it means "no options"

so what's the different between both below?

```
NSStringCompareOptions()

NSStringCompareOptions(rawValue:0)
```

Thank you very much for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a better understanding, you should look at the definition of [`OptionSetType`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_OptionSetType_Protocol/index.html), which is the protocol which NSStringCompareOptions conforms to.

In addition to the basic protocol definition, you will find some extensions:

```
extension OptionSetType where RawValue : BitwiseOperationsType {
    /// Create an empty instance.
    ///
    /// - Equivalent to `[] as Self`
    public convenience init()
    ...
}
```

And the [`SetAlgebraType`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_SetAlgebraType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intf/s:PSs14SetAlgebraType) protocol which OptionSetType conforms to:

```
extension SetAlgebraType {
    /// Creates the set containing all elements of `sequence`.
    public convenience init<S : SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Element>(_ sequence: S)
    ...
}
```

The fact that these methods are in protocol `extension`s indicates that they have default implementations which are automatically provided.

You can read more about option sets in [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html).

Comment: Thank you ! It's very helpful, I get much on it.

Answer (score 0):

Both are same `NSStringCompareOptions()` and `NSStringCompareOptions(rawValue:0)`

There is no deffernce. you can used any of those.

Good Luck and Happy coding

Comment: Ideally, we shouldn't use either. The best solution for option sets is to just use `[]`.

Comment: Thank you , I got it. :)